# How do I differentiate source of scrollViewDidScroll call when both UITableView and UIScrollView are present?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I am using both a `UITableView` and `UIScrollView` inside the same `UIViewController`.

My problem is when I scroll either the table view or scroll view the didScroll delegate call is fired.

How can i identify the source of the `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate call?

Answer (score 15):

check the scrollView parameter given in the delegate.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if(scrollView == self.tableView) {
      // its your tableView
    }
    else if(scrollView == self.scrollView) {
      // its your scrollView
    }
}
```

Comment: He i use these lines of code but it not working.Can you please tell me another way.?

Comment: It's Solved now .if(sender == tableview)

Answer (score 3):

The didScroll method takes in a scrollview as an input

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    if(scrollView == self.tableViewInstance){//this is  your table view}
    else {//this is your scroll view}
}
```

You can check the input and see whether it is your scrollview or tableview which is calling the delegate method.

Comment: i used it [scrollView.subviews containsObject:tableView] but it's not working ..Can you please give me example

Answer (score 1):

You can add tag for UIScrollView as `0` and add tag for UITableView as `1`. Inside the delegate check for the tag to know which of this is scrolled and do your stuff:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
  {
       if(scrollViewl.tag == 0) // ur in scrollView
        if(scrollViewl.tag == 1) // ur in tableView
   }
```

Comment: :Your if condition became always true .It will not work..any other idea please share..:)

Comment: Did you set the tag for scrollView and tableView?